# title of the subview covered by background image of that subview (iphone)

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, background-image, title

I have a subview on my main view which pops up using tap.

I set a background image to it but now the title is covered . what do I need to do to fix this? SHOULD I change anything in viewDidLoad?

here is how I have added the background image:

```
 UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, ViewHeight, kDeviceWidth, 230.0);

    container.opaque = NO;
    container.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.formView addSubview:imageView];
    [self.formView addSubview:frame];
```

Comment: what you want...  you want to add background image to frame?

Comment: I have added the background image to my subview, but the title of that is covered by the background image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every layer has property called zPosition. By changing zPosition you can manipulate the order of drawing the layers.
CALayers with greater zPosition cover the CALayers, that have smaller zPosition. zPosition is by default 0, so setting -1 value for the background image layer should work.

To change this property you have to use QuartzCore framework: click on Project - Targets - ProjectName - Build Phases - Link Binary With Libraries - Plus - QuartzCore.

```
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

imageView.layer.zPosition = -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add title on top of background image then you need to add title to image view like this

```
[imageView addSubview title];
```

if you want to add title on top of form view then do this

```
[self.formView addSubview:imageView];

[self.formView addSubview:title];
```

Hope it helps.